# Are there any Open Source alternatives to Crystal Reports?

Tags: open-source, crystal-reports

Are there any Open Source alternatives to Crystal Reports?

Comment: Why is this a CW or tagged subjective?

Comment: It depends what you want to achieve. Can you tell us a little more about how you'd like to use the reporting tool.

Comment: @Geoffrey Chetwood: I would guess its a CW since its a "list"-question with no objective correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

[JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) if you're writing Java.

Answer (score 4):

The java standard answer is often:

- JasperReports: http://jasperforge.org
- iReport: http://ireport.sourceforge.net
- openreports: http://oreports.com/

Answer (score 3):

Report Manager has been around for quite a few years.  It's written in Delphi (at least it was originally) and has components that can be used in Delphi, but is usable via ActiveX or dll from just about any language.  Now has a native .NET library too.  Has a nifty report-serving webserver you can set up too.  The designer gui looks and feels a little rough around the edges but it works.
http://reportman.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

How about **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear).

Though not free, you should also consider this low-cost, non-free, non-open-source reporting solution that can fully compete with Crystal Reports - and is Java-based.

I think it's even more cost efficient than "free ones". A small company may have to think closely about free things, but will then have to invest into manpower to find out how everything works and so on. Large companies will for sure subscribe to premium support services that cost a lot. [See this article for reference](http://www.inetsoftware.de/support/news/why-i-net-crystal-clear-costs-less-than-open-source)

[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear) has a very low price tag with great support for free and even better premium support via yearly subscriptions.

*Disclosure: Yeah, I work for the company who built this, so I'm biased. But I honestly believe in what I just wrote.*

Comment: BTW: If you're just looking for something free: check out our Free Designer Edition - it is fully featured (just comes without the server).

Comment: With respect, starting prices of $1,690 is not a very low price tag.

Answer (score 2):

So far based on my research JasperSoft has turned out promising open source reporting tool… Matter of fact I am currently working on a huge project wherein I have started converting and building reports using JasperReports/iReports…

Every reporting tool has its own learning curve.  The support group from and for Jasper and the quality of response that I have gotten so far is good.

Again at the end of the day it all comes down to what your business / organization needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jasper report.

iReport is a very effective tool to develop jasper reports.

It supports almost all the facilities provided by crystal report like formatting, grouping, creation of charts etc.

Refer the link for tutorial:

http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/Tutorial_iReports

Answer (score 0):

[iReport](http://ireport.sourceforge.net/cap3.html)